# How to bind mouse wheel to zoom not tilt

Tags: customization, shortcut

I can not for the life of me work out or find out why or how Blender is now tilting the view with the mouse wheel.

What have I done? How can I get the mouse wheel to zoom in and out and not tilt.

All of the input preferences appear to be correct.

Comment: If you load blender with the factory defaults (file > load factory settings), does this still happen? Have you tried resetting your keybindings in user prefs > input?

Comment: Its intermittent. It keeps changing behaviour. So just now it started zooming again. I'm thinking there might be a key i'm pressing or option/view i'm in thats switching it around?

Comment: Ctrl Shift Scroll will roll the viewport by default, not sure how they could be pressed without you knowing about it though.. ;)

Comment: Could you have a stuck or faulty key on your keyboard that is causing the intermittent behavior?

Comment: Sticky key, very possible, i guess. THough I dOn't get randOm capItals when typinG :-p